# How to use std::vector::remove() in a virtual class method?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have the following class:

```
template <class T>
class BeliefSet : public Belief<T>
{
private:
    std::vector<T> m_Facts;

public:
    void RemoveFact(const T Fact)
    {
        m_Facts.remove(Fact);
    }
};
```

This works fine. However, I want to derive another class from `BeliefSet` and override this method `RemoveFact()`, thus I changed the code shown above to the following:

```
/* Rest of this class has not been changed. */

virtual void RemoveFact(const T Fact)
{
    m_Facts.remove(Fact);
}
```

Now as soon as I compile I get this error:

```
error C2039: 'remove': is not a member of 'std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>'
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: This is not not a [mcve]

Comment: std::vector does indeed not have a remove() function. I think you're mistaken that your first example actually works.

Comment: Can you show us full working example of `remove()` that "works fine"? As far I know, `remove()` is a method of `std::list<>`, not of `std::vector<>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This works fine.

No, it doesn't. `std::vector` has no member function `remove()`. However, class template member functions aren't eagerly instantiated. It's likely that you simply never invoked `RemoveFact()`, so you never had to run into this problem. This "lazy" instantiation is very important - it lets you write and use class templates that have conditionally valid operators without writing loads of SFINAE junk (e.g. I can use `std::map` fine with non-default-constructive value types, I just can't use `operator[]`).

When you made the function `virtual`, as you as inherit from it, it is likely that your compiler attempted to instantiate the function at that point (it is unspecified whether an implementation does so - yours apparently does). Since this function is ill-formed, you get the error via the `virtual` function instantiation instead of normal function instantiation.

Either way, the function is broken and you want:

```
void RemoveFact(const T& Fact)
{
    m_Facts.erase(
        std::remove(m_Facts.begin(), m_Facts.end(), Fact),
        m_Facts.end());
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks a lot. Just for the records: I had to `#include <algorithm>` for this solution to work.